# only Last 7 days from Todays Date in zend forms

Tags: php, forms, date, zend-framework, zend-framework2

My start only show past 7 days and compare with today's date in zend form and all past dates should disable except past 7 days. I have tried to set min option in attribute section but not working. Below is my code

```
$this->add([
        'name' => 'start',
        'type' => 'Date',
        'options' => [
            'label' => 'Start Date*',
        ],
        'attributes' => [
            'id'   => 'start_date',
            'required' => 'required'
        ],
    ]);
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make two changes. 
**Pay attention**: in these snippets, I use the date format `Y-m-d`, just check that match yours ;)

## Form creation

First one, you need to add the min date to your element:

```php
$this->add([
    'name' => 'start',
    'type' => 'Date',
    'options' => [
        'label' => 'Start Date*',
    ],
    'attributes' => [
        'id' => 'start_date',
        'required' => 'required',
        'min' => ((new \DateTime())->sub(new \DateInterval('P7D')))->format('Y-m-d')
    ],
]);
```

If you print it using zend helpers, it will render it correctly:

**PHTML file**

```php
<?php $startDate = $this->form->get('start');?>
<?= $this->formLabel($startDate); ?>
<?= $this->formElement($startDate); ?>
<?= $this->formElementErrors($startDate); ?>
```

**HTML result**

```html
<label for="start_date">Start Date*</label>
<input type="date" name="start" id="start_date" required="required" min="2021-04-21" value="">
```

You can check the result [here](https://html-css-js.com/?html=%3Cp%3E%0A%09%3Clabel%20for=%22start_date%22%3E%0A%09%09%20Start%20Date*%0A%09%3C/label%3E%0A%09%3Cinput%20type=%22date%22%20name=%22start%22%20i$*$d=%22start_date%22%20required=%22required%22%20min=%222021-04-21%22%20value=%22%22%20/%3E%0A%3C/p%3E%0A&css=&js=) (and, as you can see, there is no need to include JQuery)

## Form validation

If you don't validate the user's input, there setting the min date in the input element won't be really effective (I mean, everyone can change the attribute in the HTML).
You **MUST** validate the result.

In order to do it, your form class must implement `Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface` interface.

In this snippet, I'm using the `Callback` validator, but the best (and cleanest) solution would be to create a custom validator ;)

```php
class YourForm extends Form implements InputFilterProviderInterface {

    public function init() {
        parent::init();

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'start',
            'type' => 'Date',
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Start Date*',
            ],
            'attributes' => [
                'id' => 'start_date',
                'required' => 'required',
                'min' => ((new \DateTime())->sub(new \DateInterval('P7D')))->format('Y-m-d')
            ],
        ]);
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification() {
        $inputFilter[] = [
            'name' => 'start',
            'required' => true,
            'validators' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'Date',
                    'options' => [
                        'format' => 'Y-m-d'
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'Callback',
                    'options' => [
                        'callback' => function ($value) {
                            $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value);
                            // Set time to midnight to avoid getting errors for a small difference in seconds
                            $date->setTime(0, 0, 0, 0);
                            // Get current date, set to midnight
                            $today = (new \DateTime())->setTime(0, 0, 0);
                            
                            // CHOOSE THE ONE YOU PREFER
                            
                            // Option 1
                            // One week is (7 * 24 * 60 * 60) 604'800 seconds
                            $differenceMillis = $date->getTimestamp() - $today->getTimestamp();
                            return $differenceMillis >= (-604800);
                            
                            // Option 2
                            $dateDifference = $today->diff($date);
                            return !$dateDifference->invert && $dateDifference < 7;
                           
                        },
                        'messages' => [
                            \Zend\Validator\Callback::INVALID_VALUE => 'The date is more than 7 days in the pas'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];

        return $inputFilter;
    }

}
```